# Upload and Play Audio File JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML audio tag and an HTML file input tag, as shown below. I'd like users to use the Upload File button to select a song from their computer, then play it using the audio tag.

```
<audio id="audio">
    <source src="" id="thesource" />
</audio>
<input type="file" id="upload" title="Upload File" />
```

How do I let users upload audio files from their computer and play it? This must be done locally, as it is being used in a downloadable web app I am creating.

EDIT: Long ago, after lots of hard work and rediscovering past projects, I developed a solution to this question by converting some image-uploading code from one of my past projects into audio-uploading code. Now, years after I originally asked this question, I feel stupid for not realizing that answer earlier. I posted and edited the answer down below for any people who also need this.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I originally said there was no answer -- I was wrong. I have found the answer.

```js
function handleFiles(event) {
    var files = event.target.files;
    $("#src").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(files[0]));
    document.getElementById("audio").load();
}

document.getElementById("upload").addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="upload" />
<audio id="audio" controls>
  <source src="" id="src" />
</audio>
```

This does exactly what I wanted -- it allows uploading of any audio file and plays it. Try uploading any music from your computer into the snippet.

**Note**: Browsers like Google Chrome constantly update how and when audio/video can be played for evolving convenience or security. This answer is currently working, but if it is no longer working at any point in the future, please post a comment below so I can fix any problems that emerge.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that you don't need the event to grab the file. You can just use `this.files[0]` from within the listener.

Comment: That is true, although from what I understand, if you are using the ES6 arrow functions (`() => {}`) the `this` reference is different and does not refer to what you may expect of a regular `function`. Using `event` avoids this issue altogether regardless of what type of function you are using. I didn't want people who use arrow functions to believe that the answer doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title> Majd's Music Player </title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" id="musicFile" accept="audio/*">
  <button onclick="playMusic()">Play</button>
  <audio id="musicPlayer" controls=""></audio>
  <script>
    function playMusic() {
      var musicFile = document.getElementById("musicFile").files[0];
      var musicPlayer = document.getElementById("musicPlayer");
      musicPlayer.src = URL.createObjectURL(musicFile);
      musicPlayer.play();
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.